# Number of non-negative integers solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 10$ when $x_1 > x_2$

Tags: combinatorics

Some facts (Please correct me if I am wrong)

1. When $x_1=x_2$, the solution is $\sum_{k=1}^6 {2k\choose2} = 161$
2. I would like to count the bijection of the case $x_1\geqslant x_2$
3. $ 10 \geqslant x_1 \geqslant 0$
4. $ 10 \geqslant x_2 \geqslant 0$

Inference

1. $ 10 \geqslant x_1-x_2 \geqslant 0$
2. $ y_1 = x_1 - x_2$
3. $y_1 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10$
4. There are ${13\choose 3}$ ways for $x_1 \geqslant x_2 $
5. Given $x_1=x_2$ has 161 ways, $x_1>x_2$ would be ${13\choose3} - 161$

Is this bijection correct? If not, how to come up with the correct story?

[Original post that proves with law of trichotomy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583282/number-of-non-negative-integers-solutions-of-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-x-5-10?rq=1)

Comment: It would seem simpler to count as such: First, determine how many solutions occur if there's no condition on $x_1,x_2$. Since 161 of these solutions have $x_1=x_2$, the rest of them have distinct $x_1,x_2$. Of these, half will have $x_1>x_2$ and half have $x_1<x_2$.

Comment: You are right. I just wonder why my bijection headcount headcount isn't the same as the solutions of yours.
In fact, the attached link has the exact solution that you mentioned.

Comment: $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1-x_2$ isn't an injective function, so you are undercounting.

Comment: Brian, I would be grateful if you could briefly explain how usually does bijection work in these type of problems?